# How to use custom theme in Worklight Dojo App

Tags: themes, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I have a custom theme that I want to use for a dojomobile app in worklight.  How do I force worklight to use it no matter what the device it is running on?  I've tried the following and none work.  It keeps going back to the device default.

```
<script src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js" data-dojo-config="mblUserAgent: 'myui'"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false, mblUserAgent:'myui'" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not load the deviceTheme.js.  Just link to your css directly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your stylesheet is loaded after the deviceTheme.js is loaded in your main .html file.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js" data-dojo-config="mblThemeFiles: ['iphone','ipad']"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MyCSS.css">
```

Also using a tool like Chrome's Developer Tools can help you see how the CCS is parsed and which definition overrides the others.